# how to call a internal javascript function in object notation

Tags: javascript, function, object

**Solution:**
Yay, using `this.setName()` worked!

**Problem:**
1) Didn't know how to properly title this question
2) I am trying to call a `setName()` from inside of `getName()`

**Javascript:**

```
window.login
chat = {
    setName: function( ) {
    },

    getName( ) {
        //i want to call setName() here, is that possible?
        //i tried chat.setName() and setName(), both failed.
    }
}
```

Very simple question, I just am not too knowledgeable in JavaScript. Thank you for the suggestions/help/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this`. It refers to the current object:

```
chat = {
    setName: function() {
        alert('setName');
    },

    getName: function() {
        this.setName();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So simple, I just couldn't figure out for the life of me how to search for it on google :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the 'this' keyword.

```
var chat = {
    setName: function(){...},
    getName: function(){ this.setName(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chat = {
    setName: function( ) {
        alert('test');
    },

    getName: function( ) {
        this.setName();
    }
};

chat.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Try:

```
chat = {
    setName: function() {...},
    getName: function() {
        chat.setName();
    }
}
```